# sympy and numpy or IPython compatibility?

Tags: numpy, python-2.7, sympy

I found that if I have both sympy and numpy (EDIT: or IPython) installed (32-bit
windows 7), then I can only run sympy through its isympy script
file, e.g., from a git-bash console

```
pushd /c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/sympy/bin
python isympy
limit(diff(exp(-1/t**2), t, 64), t, 0)
```

crunches a few seconds then prints 0

But if I attempt to import sympy, as in

```
from sympy import Symbol, cos
```

I get a `ImportError: cannot import name Float` (full traceback below)

I can still run sympy from its `isympy` script, and I can import numpy
and scipy into a session that I start from the `isympy` script.  The
numpy and scipy printouts are different in this case from the
documented results, but they pass a tiny ad-hoc test.

Is this a known problem, or something I messed up or
misunderstand?  I will be grateful for advice, guidance, similar
experiences, etc.

BTW, I didn't use the 64-bit versions because I was also trying to install matplotlib and something went wrong with Tkinsert's not being a valid executable, I think, so I backed all the way out to 32-bit versions of everything.

EDIT:

started from scratch, installed sympy AND NOT numpy, test it 100% ok, then installed IPython.  Now `from sympy import Symbol` produces a similar stack trace.

end EDIT

Details follow:

Fresh install of Python 2.7.3 32-bit on Windows 7 into the
default directory `C:\Python27`.  Then installed sympy using a
git-bash window as follows

```
pushd /c/Python27/Lib/site-packages
git clone git://github.com/sympy/sympy.git
cd sympy
python setup.py install
```

test:

```
python setup.py test
```

runs a while, all passing.

Standard ad-hoc tests

```
from sympy import cos
x = Symbol('x')
(1/cos(x)).series(x,0,10)
```

prints

```
1 + x**2/2 + 5*x**4/24 + 61*x**6/720 + 277*x**8/8064 + O(x**10)
```

Running sympy through the `isympy` script gives prettier print

```
quit()
python /c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/sympy/bin/isympy

>>> (1/cos(x)).series(x, 0, 10)
     2      4       6        8
    x    5*x    61*x    277*x     / 10\
1 + -- + ---- + ----- + ------ + O\x  /
    2     24     720     8064
```

Now, install numpy via browser:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/numpy-1.6.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download

ad-hoc test in a fresh session

```
python
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
a
```

prints

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

but

```
from sympy import Symbol,cos
```

generates

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sympy import Symbol,cos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sympy\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from sympy.core import *
  File "sympy\sympy\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from polys import *
  File "sympy\sympy\polys\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from polytools import (
  File "sympy\sympy\polys\polytools.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sympy.polys.polyclasses import DMP
  File "sympy\polys\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from polytools import (
  File "sympy\polys\polytools.py", line 64, in <module>
    from sympy.polys.domains import FF, QQ
  File "sympy\polys\domains\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from finitefield import FiniteField
  File "sympy\polys\domains\finitefield.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sympy.polys.domains.groundtypes import SymPyIntegerType
  File "sympy\polys\domains\groundtypes.py", line 34, in <module>
    from sympy import (
                       ImportError: cannot import name Float
```

I can still run

```
python /c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/sympy/bin/isympy
```

but now

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
a
```

prints

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

instead of the expected

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: If you are using Ipython most probably there is some pretty printing hooks that are active. This is why it prints differently (isympy automatically enables certain pretty printing hooks).